# Newbie has error "Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly '"Pappa Bob's Pizza"' or one of its dependencies."

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using `Visual Studio community 2019`.
When run, the error I am getting in Edge is:-
`"Could not load file or assembly '"Pappa Bob's Pizza"' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"`

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: `System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '"Pappa Bob's Pizza"' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`

I think it is to do with my HTML/ASP code, as I have commented out my C# code. I don't get any compilation errors.

The first line of the HTML has a blue line beneath it stating the error.

This is the line of code that Visual Studio has underlined in blue. It is the top of the HTML:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pappa_Bob_s_Pizza.Default" %>
```

Can anyone help me determine the cause of this exception?

Thank You.

Comment: Where does that phrase "Pappa Bob's Pizza" come from in your code, especially that `'`? Maybe you need to recreate this project, but without non-alphanumerics in its name (no spaces or quotes)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for getting back to me. I removed the ' but unfortunately it did not clear the error. The blue line still is beneath the text
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pappa_Bob_s_Pizza.Default" %>
[What I see in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3qbs.jpg)